# Why content.render renders nothing?

Tags: fedext

I'm new to the fluidcontent stuff. To get into the stuff, I have work with the documentation. But now I am at a point I don't know where my fault is.

I have add the Skeltron of the HTML Layout. But now I wondering why the content which is set into the Typo3 Backend don't be rendered.

Page.html

```
<f:layout name="Page" />
<f:render section="Main" />
<div id="page" class="{settings.pageClass}">
<div id="sidebar">
    <f:render section="Sidebar" />
</div>
<div id="content">
    <f:render section="Content" />
</div>
</div>`
```

MyPageTemplate.html

```
<f:layout name="Page" />
<f:section name="Configuration">
<flux:form id="fluidfluxform" label="Fluid/FluxForm" icon="{f:uri.resource(path:      'Icons/Page.gif')}">
    <!-- Input field for Fluid variable 'pageClass' -->
    <flux:field.input name="settings.pageClass" default="some-css-class" />

    <!-- Backend layout grid (TYPO3 6.x and greater only) -->
    <flux:grid>
        <flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.column colPos="1" name="Content" style="width: 75%" />
            <flux:grid.column colPos="0" name="Sidebar" style="width: 25%" />
        </flux:grid.row>
    </flux:grid>
    </flux:form>
    </f:section>

 <f:section name="Main">
Main render
 </f:section>

<f:section name="Content">
  <!-- Render colPos=0 in this section -->
  fdgfdgfdg
  <v:content.render column="1" />
</f:section>


<f:section name="Sidebar">
  <!-- Render colPos=1 in this section -->
  sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
  <v:content.render column="0" />
</f:section>
```

The provder extension TypoScript in page config is added. The Page.html skeletron is shown and the fgfgfgffg, sdfsdfsdf and Main render is shown, too. Only render.content don't work.

Has someone a idea?

Typo 6.2.4 - Apache - Ubuntu.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include it in your code examples so just in case: have you remembered to include the namespaces of both Flux and VHS in your template code?

`{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}`

In both templates. Example code assumes you are using the most recent versions of both VHS and Flux (e.g. the PHP namespaces based versions).